# Unity: DontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity

I'm viewing tutorial of Unity. In this tutorial, I see this piece of code:

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameControl control;

    public void Awake() {
        if (control == null) {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            control = this;
        } else if (control != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand above code very much. I just understand the first if. it means: when we first use this class, we will initialize control object and set attribute `dontdestroyonload` for this. But I don't understand second if, when will it meet condition `control != this` ?

Thanks :)

Comment: The code would be more understandable if it just used `else` instead of `else if (control != this)`. Cf. [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: @Eric Except, the next time the scene changes, `control` is no longer `null`, and the object containing the `GameControl` script would be destroyed. There's a reason it's `else if`.

Comment: @Byte56 `Awake` is called once in a script instance's lifetime, not on each scene change. So the first `GameControl` instance would assign itself to `GameControl.control` in its `Awake` and any further `GameControl` instances will destroy themselves in their `Awake`s.

Comment: @Eric You're correct, in this case it would make more sense to just use `else`.

Comment: so. we really don't need second else ? this code I wrap from Unity's tutorial. It means it is written by Unity Programmer. So hardly to think no effect for second else if.

Answer (score 2):

This is the implementation of a very simple version of a programming pattern called [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). For more context, see [Unity Singleton Pattern](http://unitypatterns.com/singletons/).

The basic idea is, the designer wants that there should only be one instance of the `GameControl` object. Therefore, before everything else (in `Awake()` function), the designer checks if the object is initialized or not. This first case of if the case that the object is not initialized, thus being the first instance of the object.

The second case is, the scene is changed and the same object is present in the new scene hierarchy, therefore `control` is already assigned and thus not equal to `this`. In this case, remove the newly created object from the scene.

Answer (score 1):

The `control` variable is a static variable. The code you're looking at is for ensuring there's always a `GameControl` object in the world, and *only one*.

The first time a `GameControl` object is loaded, `control` is set. If a `GameControl` is ever attempted to be loaded again, it will not match the already loaded `control` object and will be destroyed.

Comment: Can you tell me. `gameObject` stands for which object ? I though it stands for GameControl itself. but as your explanation, it's not. right ?

Comment: In this case, `gameObject` is short for `this.gameObject`. It's the GameOject that belongs to the script currently running. Remember that scripts are attached to game objects, so the GameControl is not an object on its own, but rather a script attached to a game object.

Comment: Ah. that's object in unity scene that we often attach script into. So, why `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` helps saving `gameObject` (and `GameControl` object attach to its) when changing scene but `OnDestroy(gameObject)`, `GameControl` object doesn't destroy too ? (I guess `GameControl` object doesn't destroy, because if it destroyed, singleton pattern is failed in this case)

Comment: [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) preserves an object between scene changes. [`Destroy`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) (not `OnDestroy`, which is an event that's called when an object is destroyed) removes the game object from the scene. The singleton pattern is preserved because once a `GameControl` object is created, it can only be destroyed if you explicitly destroy it, and not accidentally through a scene change.

Comment: oh. so why should we use `DontDestroyOnLoad` and `Destroy` in this case ? Because as you see, `GameControl` object can only be destroyed if i explicitly destroy it. thanks :)

Comment: As I mentioned, `DontDestroyOnLoad` protects the object from being accidentally destroyed during scene changes. `Destroy` destroys any additional objects containing the script `GameControl` to ensure there's only ever one instance.